# what permissions are needed for writing to uls logs?

Tags: sharepoint

We have creates a webpart and in the catch block we are writing logs to uls.

My concern is regarding permission to write to this log. Will users with read-only access to sharepoint face no issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure SPDiagnosticsService.WriteTrace(...) always uses the current application pool's account access, regardless of which logged-in user invoked the current request. If the app pool account is not a farm administrator account you need to add it to the 'Performance Log Users' group.
But to make it explicit you could use SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(...).